# How to label smart meter/plug data (time series)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, data, labels

I would like to label smart plug data recorded in different household appliances so that I can train a machine to recognize for example when the oven is turned on. I am new to this topic and I am looking for tools/approaches that help me get started. The data would be time stamps and power consumption values.

**Edit because the question was too broad
The data would be in .csv format and I would use samples of the data where I KNOW what the appliance is doing, so that I can label it correctly. For example a washing machine on a delicate cycle or on a regular cycle.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site. Could you please clarify the format of your data? For example, to recognise that the oven is turned on, do you have possible characteristics of consumption appliances, or is it that you just have data of total consumption (maybe per hour)?

Comment: Hello, thanks. The format would probably be .csv format ( I still don't have access to it, since I am waiting on the smart plug). I would use the patterns I know to label the datasets, for example when the washing machine is doing different cycles the power consumption will be different. The time is also a variable to take into account, since the cycles will last differently too.

Comment: I don't know if I answered the question right, but what I mean is that the smart plug is connected to ONE appliance and I will know exactly what's happening by looking at the recorded data. I want to label the datasets according to what I know it's happening, for example the washing machine cycles, so that later on this pattern is recognized.

Comment: The fact that your meter is connected to only one appliance simplifies things a lot. I'd suggest you also add this information and this way you will be able to claim that the question is specific enough to be released from the hold.

Comment: Another thing to consider is whether it makes sense for you to have a [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)) in your model? In other words, is it relevant what the machine was doing at the previous measure, or is the consumption sufficient information to decide on the current actvity?